# OpenCV for iOS - Linking Libraries in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

As part of a team project I intend to implement obstacle detection for a robot using open cv. I am now at a point where I have functional code that runs on OS X and uses my laptop camera to detect obstacles approaching it. However the robot runs iOS (it is an iPad at heart) and thus requires me to build for iOS. Obviously the linker now doesn't accept the OS X library files, because of architecture mismatches. So far it is set up as follows:
 1. `/usr/local/lib` added to `Library Search Paths`
 2. `/usr/local/include` added to `Header Search Paths`
 3. c++ language dialect changed to `C++11`
 4. Libraries added to `Other Linker Flags` ( `-lopencv_calib3d` etc.)
 5. `Valid Architectures` set to `i386`,`x86_64`

In order to perform the necessary modifications for iOS I first of all changed the valid architectures to `armv7`, `armv7s`, and `arm64`. Then I attempted to follow the instructions on [OpenCV:Installation in iOS](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html), asking me to execute the `opencv/platforms/ios/build_framework.py` script. This built a framework file and a folder `build`. I added the framework file to my Xcode project via `Build Phases` -> `Link Binary With Libraries.` According to the python script's `readme` "The script builds OpenCV.framework for iOS. The built framework is universal, it can be used to build app and run it on either iOS simulator or real device." However when I try to build the product for iOS simulator (amongst others), I get uncountable `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` linker errors. As far as I am aware there is nothing else to the installation instructions linked above though.

Am I missing something here? Adjusting header/library search paths to include either nothing or the OS X OpenCV library files from `/usr/local/lib` was to no avail. My intuition is that is has something to do with the folder `build` created by the python script alongside the `opencv2.framework` file. The contents of `build` are the folders:
iPhoneOS-arm64
iPhoneOS-armv7
iPhoneOS-armv7s
iPhoneSimulator-i386
iPhoneSimulator-x86_64

These in turn are comprised of:

[image]

Do I need to link any part of these folders into my project?

I am grateful for any advice.

Warm regards,
Mark

EDIT: Here are the linker errors I get when compiling for iOS simulator. When compiling for another architecture x (for example armv7) I get the exact same errors, differing only in the line `Undefined symbols for architecture x`.

> Ld
>   /Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Double_IRL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Double_IRL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Double_IRL
>   normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/Double IRL Project/Double_IRL"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk
>   -L/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/Double\ IRL\ Project/Double_IRL/..
>   -F/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/Programming_Tools/ios -filelist /Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Double_IRL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Double_IRL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Double_IRL.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -stdlib=libc++ -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework opencv2 -framework DoubleControlSDK -framework ExternalAccessory -framework UIKit
>   -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Double_IRL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Double_IRL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Double_IRL_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Double_IRL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Double_IRL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Double_IRL
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_AVFileType3GPP", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_AVFileTypeAppleM4V", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_AVFileTypeMPEG4", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_AVMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::CvCaptureFile(char const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_AVVideoCodecH264", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_AVVideoCodecJPEG", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_AVVideoCodecKey", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_AVVideoHeightKey", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_AVVideoWidthKey", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in
>   opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CMSampleBufferInvalidate", referenced
>   from:
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetPresentationDimensions", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::getProperty(int) const in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVBufferRelease", referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in
>   opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVBufferRetain", referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in
>   opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes",
>   referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced
>   from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced
>   from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferRelease", referenced
>   from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetReader",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetReaderTrackOutput", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetWriter", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetWriterInput", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDeviceInput", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureSession", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureVideoDataOutput", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVURLAsset", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_kCMTimeZero", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_kCVPixelBufferHeightKey", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::CvCaptureFile(char const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_kCVPixelBufferWidthKey", referenced
>   from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

EDIT2: Errors left after adding AV foundation framework.

> Ld
>   /Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Double_IRL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Double_IRL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Double_IRL
>   normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/Double IRL Project/Double_IRL"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk
>   -L/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/Double\ IRL\ Project/Double_IRL/..
>   -F/Users/schuegrafm/Documents/Programming_Tools/ios -filelist /Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Double_IRL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Double_IRL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Double_IRL.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -stdlib=libc++ -mios-simulator-version-min=6.0 -framework AVFoundation -framework opencv2 -framework DoubleControlSDK -framework ExternalAccessory
>   -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Double_IRL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Double_IRL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Double_IRL_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/schuegrafm/Documents/SS15/CooperativeRobots/SDK/DoubleBasicHelloWorld/build/Double_IRL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Double_IRL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Double_IRL
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in
>   opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CMSampleBufferInvalidate", referenced
>   from:
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetPresentationDimensions", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::getProperty(int) const in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVBufferRelease", referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in
>   opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVBufferRetain", referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in
>   opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes",
>   referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced
>   from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced
>   from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferRelease", referenced
>   from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_kCMTimeZero", referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation(char const*, int, double, CvSize, int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>   "_kCVPixelBufferHeightKey", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::CvCaptureFile(char const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_kCVPixelBufferWidthKey", referenced
>   from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

EDIT3: Remaining 14 errors.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_CVBufferRelease",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in
>   opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVBufferRetain", referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in
>   opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes",
>   referenced from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetHeight", referenced
>   from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferGetWidth", referenced
>   from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferRelease", referenced
>   from:
>         CvVideoWriter_AVFoundation::writeFrame(_IplImage const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress",
>   referenced from:
>         -[CaptureDelegate updateImage] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::retrieveFramePixelBuffer() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_kCVPixelBufferHeightKey", referenced
>   from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey", referenced from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureFile::CvCaptureFile(char const*) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)   "_kCVPixelBufferWidthKey", referenced
>   from:
>         CvCaptureCAM::startCaptureDevice(int) in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
>         CvCaptureCAM::setWidthHeight() in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Why don't you use iOS framework available for download?

Comment: The downloadable file is identical to the framework file the script built. It also only consists of header files.

Comment: The issue I have is with the linking of the source files. Linking is not mentioned at all in the tutorial on the opencv site.

Comment: Provide linker errors.

Comment: Add AVFoundation framework to project.

Comment: Wow thanks very much, that reduced the number of errors from 40 to 19. Remaining errors appended to end of post.

Comment: It is CoreMedia framework. I think that all this described in documentation to OpenCV.

Comment: Really? Would you mind linking that to me? I've been very frustrated attempting to get this to work the past days. It's definitely not on the iOS page. You do not know how grateful I am for your help, it really means a lot. If you could help me get rid of the last 14 errors, that would be amazing.

Comment: It is a CoreVideo framework. You could find several tutorials at OpenCV official site for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-last-rst/doc/tutorials/ios/table_of_content_ios/table_of_content_ios.html#table-of-content-ios) for iOS on official OpenCV site. You will there information about dependencies.

Comment: Ah I did not realize there were actual differences in the code, this is a real eye-opener. Thanks again for your support, have a nice day!

Comment: please post some useful content rather than just give a link

Answer (score 0):

To import OpenCV 3 into your Xcode 8 project:

1. Install 'OpenCV2' with Cocoapods (it says '2', but it's still version 3). Don't install the 'devel' build.
2. Open your project in the workspace Cocoapods created for you — not the project file you created — and append every implementation file that uses OpenCV with .mm (versus .m). You'll get strange error messages if you don't.